# MyPy - "Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type None, variable has type ...)"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I've got the following function, which given a string of the form `'a-02/b-03/foobarbaz_c-04'`, will extract the digits after *a*, *b* and *c*. The issue is that, for my use case, the input strings may not contain *c*, such that there will be no digits to extract.

Here's the code:

```
from typing import Tuple, Optional


def regex_a_b_c(name: str) -> Tuple[int, int, Optional[int]]:
        a_b_info = re.search('a-(\d\d)/b-(\d\d)/', name)
        a, b = [int(a_b_info.group(x)) for x in range(1, 3)]
        c_info = re.search('c-(\d\d)', name)
        if c_info:
            c = int(c_info.group(1))
        else:
            c = None   
        return a, b, c
```

The issue I have is that, despite trying to make it clear that the last return argument is an `Optional[int]`, I can't get my linter to stop complaining about the variable c.

I get a warning at the line `c = None` that says:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type None, variable
> has type int)

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't annotate a variable, mypy will [infer its type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html) based on the very first assignment it sees.

So in this case, the line `c = int(_info.group(1))` appears first, so mypy decides that the type must be `int`. It then subsequently complains when it sees `c = None`.

One way of working around this limitation is to just forward-declare the variable with the expected type. If you are using Python 3.6+ and can use variable annotations, you can do so like this:

```
c: Optional[int]
if c_info:
    c = int(c_info.group(1))
else:
    c = None
```

Or perhaps more concisely, like this:

```
c: Optional[int] = None
if c_info:
    c = int(c_info.group(1))
```

If you need to support older versions of Python, you can annotate the type using the comment-based syntax, like so:

```
c = None  # type: Optional[int]
if c_info:
    c = int(c_info.group(1))
```

rje's suggestion of doing:

```
if c_info:
    c = int(c_info.group(1))
    return a, b, c
else:
    return a, b, None
```

...is also a reasonable one.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the nice approach given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860650/730150), I came across another way to get mypy to ignore the line by adding  comment like the following:

```
c = None    # type: ignore
```

This seems to ignore the type for the current line, but does not effect the type inference for the other areas where the variable is used.

Comment: Don’t know why this was downvoted, it’s the best answer in my opinion: because mypy is a type annotation program, it’s not supposed to cause you to restructure your code (which all the other answers do). Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm downvoting because this *breaks* type inference - mypy will treat `c` as having type `int` instead of type `Optional[int]`, and will treat all `int` operations as valid on `c`, even though `c` could be `None`.

Comment: I agree with Louis here, for now this is the best solution. This honestly seems like a shortcoming of MyPy. Just because it is incapable of updating its inferred type, doesn't mean that we should refactor to something less readable/intuitive. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should return either a tuple `a,b,c` or a tuple `a,b` without including c. This way you do not need to assign a value of None to c at all.

```
if c_info:
    c = int(c_info.group(1))
    return a, b, c
else:
    return a, b
```

Comment: But that's the reason why I defined the return type to have an `Optional[int]`. Is there really no way around it?

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's unfortunately suboptimal in that it doesn't allow me to easily unpack the results when I use the function. That's why I wanted a tuple of int, int, Optional[int].

Comment: Hmm. Did you try declaring c as an optional int, e.g. `c: Optional[int] = None`?