# How to use Optional correctly when assigning to None?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

I have a similar problems as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52822933/1534017) which I can reproduce with the following example (using py3.8); I have two classes like this:

```
from typing import Optional


class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class A:

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        clb: Optional[B] = None,
    ):
        self.name = name

        if clb is not None:
            if isinstance(clb, B):
                self.clb = clb
            else:
                raise TypeError("clb has to be of type B.")
        else:
            self.clb = None
```

If I now do

```
mypy filename.py
```

I will receive

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None",
> variable has type "B")

I can get rid of this error if I do

```
self.name = name
self.clb = None

if clb is not None:
    ...
```

Is there another way to avoid this error?

Comment: You can try the same thing as in the question you linked: annotate `self.clb` with `Optional[B]`. Alternatively rewrite your logic and only do a single assignment to `self.clb`

Comment: @Wombatz: Yes, I could, but if I then ever want to update the type of `clb` I would have to update it in two places; not dramatic, but also not that nice...

Comment: @Cleb Please add this restriction to the question itself. Otherwise, it is a perfect duplicate of the question you linked yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compress the check into a single test that covers all possible variants. Perform a single assignment with the result:

```
    if clb is None or isinstance(clb, B):
        self.clb = clb
    else:
        raise TypeError("clb has to be of type B.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to only assign to the variable  in one place.

```
def __init__(self, name: str, clb: Optional[B] = None):
    self.name = name
    self.clb = clb
```

In my opinion you should get rid of the `isinstance` check completely. Mypy is now responsible for checking your types, the manual check is somewhat redundant.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would now also raise a `TypeError` when `clb` is `None`, but that should not be the case as it is an optional argument.

Comment: True, i will remove the check from my answer. If you need it use MisterMiyagi's answer